# Guard "Could not find table"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn Rails and the TDD style of doing things. I have an issue with Guard in which it cannot find table `tasks`. The string thing is when I run the Rails console and perform Task.all, I find the table I am looking for. I have restarted guard numerous times. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Are you running the rails console in test mode? (`rails c test`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Execute `rake db:migrate db:test:prepare` in the command line to ensure that your test database has the same schema as the development database.